# ActiveRecord combining relations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel

I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do this:

I have 2 complex relations with multiple joins joining to Table D. I want to combine/join them to get the Table D records. The following works but is there a better way?

```
class TableD < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.relation_three
  r1 = TableA.relation_one.select("d.id")
  r2 = TableB.relation_two.select("d.id")
  where("d.id IN (#{r1.to_sql}) OR d.id IN (#{r2.to_sql})")
end
```

And if that's not possible then I have a supplementary question:

Is it possible to return an active record result class different from the record the query is based on? ie:

```
TableA.all.joins(:b).select("b.*") # Coerce into TableB class ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the actual (or representative) models? How is `TableA.relation_one` and `TableB.relation_one`related to `TableD`?